# Using Switchy - need some help (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery

So like my title suggests. I'm using switchy to create switches on my site. Now, one is working perfectly. But I need 6, and I can't get more than one to work at a time, even with different IDs/names.

Can anyone help?

```
$('#switch-me').switchy();

     <select id='switch-me'>
        <option value='on'>on</option>
        <option value='off'>off</option>
      </select>
```

Thanks

--

```
 <link href="CSS/switchy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.animate-color.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.event.drag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/switchy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
    $(".switch").switchy();

    </script>
  <select class="switch">
  <option value="female">female</option>
  <option value="male">male</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="false">false</option>
  <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you post your code, people can help you figure out what's wrong with it. But if you don't, well, it's hard to work in a vacuum.

Comment: $('#switch-me').switchy();

and then 

<div id="trends_switch"> 
         <select id='switch-me'>
            <option value='on'>on</option>
            <option value='off'>off</option>
          </select>
         
       </div>

this works fine, I just can't repeat the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** as of your edit:

The problem is that you are running the

```
$(".switch").switchy();
```

line **before** those elements exist in the DOM, because you've put it outside your `ready` handler, but above the elements in the HTML file:

```
$(function() {
    // The code in here will wait for "DOM ready"
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        /* ... */
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        /* ... */
    });
});
// But *this* will run *immediately*, and not find the elements, because they
// don't exist yet
$(".switch").switchy();
```

Just move your `script` to the *end* of your `body` (just before the closing `</body>` tag), which is best anyway, or move the `switchy` line *into* your `ready` handler.

Here's my JSBin updated so you can see exactly where the `script` is: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ozemep/4) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ozemep/4/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lou.github.io/switchy/switchy.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://lou.github.io/switchy/switchy.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="female">female</option>
  <option value="male">male</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="false">false</option>
  <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
<script>
// Note that this is *after* the elements above, and
// so they exist when it runs
$(".switch").switchy();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Original answer** (which seems to be the source of your edit):

Looking at [the switchy site](https://github.com/lou/switchy), this would appear to be as simple as:

```
<select class="switch">
  <option value="female">female</option>
  <option value="male">male</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
<select class="switch">
  <option value="false">false</option>
  <option value="true">true</option>
</select>
```

And then:

```
$(".switch").switchy();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ozemep/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ozemep/1/edit)

The key here being that the selector we feed into `$()` needs to select more than one element, not just one. In the code you posted as a comment, you're only selecting *one* element (the one with the `id` `"switch-me"`). In the above, I've used a class instead, so that I can select all three of my `select` elements, and then trigger the `switchy` plug-in on them.

Comment: I've tried that before, it adds more drop down lists but doesn't apply the styles.

Comment: @JoPoptartHoward: It does for me, see the live example I've added to the answer. You need the `switchy.css` file, perhaps you forgot that?

Comment: I have that, i've even edited it to change the style. I just can't work out why it's not working. I even copied the code you added and it still wouldn't work which is making me think it's not that, it's something else effecting it.

Comment: @JoPoptartHoward: It sounds like there's an error in your code preventing the `...switchy()` line from running at all. You'll need to find that error (for instance, in the JavaScript console, or by single-stepping through the code in the debugger -- your browser has one, or if it doesn't, switch to using a newer browser). Good luck,

Comment: @JoPoptartHoward: I just saw your edit. The problem is you're calling `switchy()` too soon. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! :) I had to copy your code to get it to work as mine didn't seem to want to work, but it's working none the less. Thanks for the help